# Deferring Script wp-i18n causes a console error 'wp is not defined' - Gravityforms

Tags: javascript, errors, seo, plugin-gravity-forms, optimization

I am deferring JS scripts in order to optimize page load times and SEO.  My code to defer scripts is something like:

```
add_filter(
    'script_loader_tag', // Filters the HTML script tag of an enqueued script.
    function ( $tag, $handle ) {
        return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
    }
);
```

It works fine for most scripts.  However, when it defers scripts like `wp-i18n`, it causes the error because of the `-js-after` code that it tries to run before the it executes the deferred script.

```
<script type='text/javascript' defer="defer" src='http://192.168.1.71/wp-includes/js/dist/i18n.min.js?ver=db9a9a37da262883343e941c3731bc67' id='wp-i18n-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' id='wp-i18n-js-after'>
wp.i18n.setLocaleData( { 'text direction\u0004ltr': [ 'ltr' ] } );
</script>
```

It seems the problem is that the script is deferred in contrast to its `-js-after` script.  I need a solution that does one of the following.

- Skips deferring scripts that have a `-js-after`
- Deferrs the `js-after` along with the script.

Implementing the first option using using

```
$data = $wp_scripts->get_data( 'wp-i18n', 'data' );
```

does not work because $data does not contain information as to whether the script has a `-js-after`.  Searching for "detecting 'WordPress -js-after'" does not give any helpful results.

Comment: I'm assuming this is on the frontend? Not all javascript can or should be deferred, and `js-after` isn't what you should be looking for, these look to be scripts added via `wp_add_inline_script`. Can an inline script even be deferred? I don't think it makes sense

Comment: Yes this is for the frontend.  enqueue of wp-i18n triggers the added inline script.  When wp-i18n gets deferred, which it can be deferred, it causes the error.  Is there a way to detect if a script like wp-i18n has a corresponding inline script?  What should I be looking for?  Should I just hard code wp-i18n not to be deferred?  What about others that are similar?

Comment: Gravityforms plugin has `$assets[] = new GF_Script_Asset( 'wp-a11y' );` in `form_display.php`.  `wp-i18n` is a dependency of `wp-a11y`.  Therefore it comes out `wp-i18n` is enqueued on the frontend when there is a form display.

Comment: In general, I'd probably seek to manually choose which scripts are deferred rather than attempting to defer them all and except some few - as Tom implies, it can break a lot of things. It's probably possible to discern which scripts have `wp_add_inline_script()`/`wp_localize_script()` inline dependencies by digging through the registry in the `$wp_scripts` global, probably at both the `wp_print_scripts` action as well as `wp_footer`.

Comment: You defer a script if it can be loaded later. If there's a script that depends on it, then it can't be loaded later and shouldn't be deferred.